# Add data only once

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am updating data and then I am adding them back to my list. However if I pres the update button few times on the row I will get the same line repeated few times. Can you please help how to add updated data without duplication?

First I remove

```
private void OnItemSelected(DocumentData selectedItem)
        {
            var index = Results.IndexOf(selectedItem);
            Results.Remove(selectedItem);
            Navigation.PushPopupAsync(new EditPopUp(selectedItem, this, index));
        }
```

And then I update

```
 public void UpdateValue(DocumentData selectedItem, int index)
        {
           var detail = new DocumentData()
           {
               FieldValue = selectedItem.FieldValue,
               FieldDescriptor = selectedItem.FieldDescriptor,
               Size = LoadSize(),
               Padding = LoadPadding(),
           };
            Results.Insert(index, detail);
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for the existence of a matching item before you insert

```
var exists = Results.Any(r => r.FieldValue == selectedItem.FieldValue && r.FieldDescriptor == selectedItem.FieldDescriptor);

if (!exists) {
    var detail = new DocumentData()
           {
               FieldValue = selectedItem.FieldValue,
               FieldDescriptor = selectedItem.FieldDescriptor,
               Size = LoadSize(),
               Padding = LoadPadding(),
           };
    Results.Insert(index, detail);
}
```